# $\lim b_n-b=0$ is it correct to write down this?

Tags: calculus, analysis

$\lim b_n-b=0$ Let $b_n$ be a convergent seq, converging to $b$. Now I am asking myself whether it would be correct to write down this, since $\lim b_n=b |-b\Leftrightarrow \lim b_n-b=0$ The questions occured since we technically dont say that $|b_n-b|=0$ but rather $|b_n-b|<\epsilon$ for all $n>N$ Thanks in advance.

Because I believe that this is only notation to say that $b_n$ is convergent.

Comment: If $\lim _n b_n = b$ then it is indeed true that $\lim _n (b_n -b)=0$. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Arrow thats exactly what i mean, thanks for your answer

Comment: The limit of a constant is just that constant again, $\lim_{k\to\infty} 3=3$, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(b_n)$ a sequence that converges to $b$. So, it means that, for all $\varepsilon >0$ there is $N_\varepsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
$$|b_n - b| < \varepsilon, \forall n \ge N.$$
But it means that, given $\varepsilon > 0$, $|(b_n - b) - 0| < \varepsilon$, for all $n \ge N_\varepsilon$. So, by definition of limit of a sequence, we can say that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(b_n - b) = 0.$$

Comment: Thats a great explanation, thank you.

Comment: @Maths You're welcome! :)

Comment: $\lim (b_n-b)=0$ and $(\lim b_n)-b=0$ are different assertions but they are equivalent, so if you write $\lim b_n-b=0$ then no one who understands this subject should care, except a teacher who wants to find whether $you$ understand.

Comment: Ok. But I just manipulated the expression.
 $|(b_n - b) - 0| \le |b_b - b| + |0| = |b_n - b| < \varepsilon$, if $n \ge N_\varepsilon$.